# Why Vue is throw error in language route?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I created a new Vue project using the [vue/cli 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html):  `vue create hello-world` then I say yes to all options that I was asked.

I want to add lang prefix to each route role.

So, the only file was changed is `router.ts` to [by this example](https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-i18n-starter/blob/master/src/router/routes.js):

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/:lang',
      component: {
        template: '<router-view></router-view>'
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: 'about',
          name: 'about',
          // route level code-splitting
          // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
          // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
          component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

But on the runtime I got an error:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

What does this error message mean? And how can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I've no explanation for why render functions are not being generated at compile time, but you can include the full vue+compiler by [changing the runtimecompiler option](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) in vue.config.js.

Comment: Well, this is was helpful. but why Vue/cli can't handle this scenario? this looks like "workaround"